# Integration tests without mocking vs. unit tests

Tags: automated-testing, unit-tests, integration-testing

Let's say that I have a software component A (function, class, react component, etc.) that uses three other software components B, C, D.

If I try to test fully test A (without mocks!), then I would have to basically implement (unit) tests for components A, B and C.

My question is: **should I use**:

- **Integration Tests without mocking**
- **Integration Tests with mocking + unit tests**

Any related resources are welcomed. Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it is that integration tests are actually about integrating real stuff, not mocking.

It makes sense to mock other components in your unit tests, because you are focused on your component you're implementing, so you want to filter out yet another complexity in the form of those other components, or those other components might not be implemented yet.

Therefore, I'd go for this approach:

- unit tests with mocks
- integration tests without mocks